# Hierarquia entre estilos CSS

Tags: javascript, css, css3

Estou estudando algumas formas mais eficientes para a estilização de um aplicativo utilizando temas.
A minha ideia seria usar algo assim:

```
<div class='tema-1'>
    <button class='btn btn-primary'>botão principal</button>
</div>
```

---

```
.tema-1 .btn-primary {
    background-color: green;
}
```

O problema surge quando tento utilizar hierarquia entre os temas:

```
<div class='tema-2'>
    <button class='btn btn-primary'>botão principal tema 2</button>

    <div class='tema-1'>
        <button class='btn btn-primary'>botão principal tema 1</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.tema-1 {
    background-color: green;
}

.tema-2 {
    background-color: red;
}
```

No exemplo, o botão pertencente ao `tema-1` (que está abaixo do `tema-2`) continua recebendo os estilos do `tema-2`.
Entendo que os estilos do `tema-2` possuem prioridade sobre os do `tema-1` devido a ordem que são inseridos no css, mas a minha pergunta é, há alguma forma de chegar ao comportamento esperado utilizando CSS? E utilizando JS?

Comment: O `tema-1` é suposto estar dentro do`tema-2` no HTML? Não me parece correcto pela sua hierarquia...

Comment: Isto não deveria estar dentro de uma função `if/else` em `PHP` ou `Javascript`? Porque pelo que estou a perceber o queres fazer aqui é: se a opção do `tema-1` estiver selecionada - correr o código HTML `<div class='tema-1'></div>` ou se a opção `tema-2` estiver selecionada - `<div class='tema-2'></div>`

Comment: A intencão é que cada tema sobrescreva o anterior respeitando a ordem no html. Os nomes numerados são apenas exemplos.

Comment: Dá uma olhada na [**na minha resposta**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/71893/11886) @Oeslei . Se ela te ajudou a resolver o teu problema, por favor considera marcá-la como correta. =)

Comment: @Chun Coloquei na pergunta apenas um exemplo simples. A mudança não é apenas para o `background`. Eu gostaria de conseguir aplicar os estilos aos elementos conforme o tema mais próximo definido. Tome como exemplo o `RelativeLayout` e o `LinearLayout` do android com uma estrutura do tipo `LinearLayout > RelativeLayout > LinearLayout`.

Comment: Esse exemplo que publiquei na resposta é apenas para você ter uma noção de como aplicar os estilos depois no seu `CSS`. Você verificou também o meu exemplo no jsFiddle? Está ali também um exemplo no jsFiddle com mais estilos como exemplo de como isso funcionaria num website real.

Answer (score 1):

O que você tem que definir primeiro são padrões.

**Qual será o padrão do botão, por exemplo ?**

Tamanho
Padding
Borda Arredondada

**O que vai mudar no botão ?**

Cor
Cor da Borda
Cor da Letra

Então,

```
// Padrão

.btn{
   width: 200px;
   height: 40px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   font-family: "Verdana";
   font-size: 14px;
   padding: 8px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

// Mudanças
.btn .red{
   background-color: red;
   color: white;
   border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[O @Chun está certo quando disse que sua "hierarquia" HTML não deveria ser implementada assim.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/71893/8493)
Todavia resolvendo o "problema", você pode incluir "prioridades" nos seus seletores, exemplo:

```
.tema-1 .btn, .tema-2 .tema-1 .btn{
    background-color:#975167;
    border-color:#774137;
}

.tema-2 .btn, .tema-1 .tema-2 .btn{
    background-color:#36c1ab;
    border-color:#26819b;
}
```

O seletor `.tema-2 .tema-1 .btn` tem predominância sobre o `.tema-2 .btn`, mesmo estando antes. Assim como o `.tema-1 .tema-2 .btn` sobre o `.tema-2 .btn`. Se você tiver 10 temas terá que fazer isso pra todos em cada regra:

```
.tema-1  .btn, 
.tema-2  .tema-1 .btn,
.tema-3  .tema-1 .btn,
.tema-4  .tema-1 .btn,
.tema-5  .tema-1 .btn,
.tema-6  .tema-1 .btn,
.tema-7  .tema-1 .btn,
.tema-8  .tema-1 .btn,
.tema-9  .tema-1 .btn,
.tema-10 .tema-1 .btn,{
    background-color:#975167;
    border-color:#774137;
}

.tema-1  .controle, 
.tema-2  .tema-1 .controle,
.tema-3  .tema-1 .controle,
.tema-4  .tema-1 .controle,
.tema-5  .tema-1 .controle,
.tema-6  .tema-1 .controle,
.tema-7  .tema-1 .controle,
.tema-8  .tema-1 .controle,
.tema-9  .tema-1 .controle,
.tema-10 .tema-1 .controle,{
    /* Regras */
}

.tema-1  .alerta, 
.tema-2  .tema-1 .alerta,
.tema-3  .tema-1 .alerta,
.tema-4  .tema-1 .alerta,
.tema-5  .tema-1 .alerta,
.tema-6  .tema-1 .alerta,
.tema-7  .tema-1 .alerta,
.tema-8  .tema-1 .alerta,
.tema-9  .tema-1 .alerta,
.tema-10 .tema-1 .alerta,{
    background-color:#975167;
    border-color:#774137;
}
```

Isso ficaria ruim de gerenciar, então você poderia usar um pre-processador, como [LESS](http://lesscss.org) ou [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/). E fazer algo como:

```
.tema-1, 
.tema-2  .tema-1,
.tema-3  .tema-1,
.tema-4  .tema-1,
.tema-5  .tema-1,
.tema-6  .tema-1,
.tema-7  .tema-1,
.tema-8  .tema-1,
.tema-9  .tema-1,
.tema-10 .tema-1{

    .btn { 
        /* Regras */ 
    }

    .controle { 
        /* Regras */ 
    }

    .alerta { 
        /* Regras */ 
    }
}
```

---

#### Exemplo funcional:

```css
.box{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
    padding:5px;
}
.box .box{margin: 10px 0 0 10px;}
.btn{
    border: 1px solid #CF8A5B;
    border-radius:2px;
    background-color: #DFAA5B;
    color:#333;
    padding:3px;
    margin:5px 0;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.tema-1 .btn, .tema-2 .tema-1 .btn{
    background-color:#975167;
    border-color:#774137;
}

.tema-2 .btn, .tema-1 .tema-2 .btn{
    background-color:#36c1ab;
    border-color:#26819b;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    Padrão: <button class="btn">Botão</button>
    <div class="box tema-2">
        Tema 2:
        <button class="btn">Botão</button>
        <div class="box tema-1">
            Tema 1:
            <button class="btn">Botão</button>
            <div class="box tema-2">
                Tema 2:
                <button class="btn">Botão</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que a sua configuração nao seja sobrescrita, coloque `!important`

```
.tema-1 {
    background-color: green !important;
}

.tema-2 {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Os problemas gerados pelo `!important` são os que mais quero evitar, e se eu quisesse que o tema-1 tivesse prioridade bastava declará-lo por último no CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Como mencionei no meu comentário acima referido na tua pergunta, não me parece que a hierarquia do teu HTML deveria ser implementada dessa maneira. Pois pelo que eu percebi, o que estás a tentar fazer aqui, é criar é um código que mude a cor do `background`, ou seja **que mude a cor do tema** conforme uma opção seja selecionada pelo usuário, como por exemplo:

```
<!-- Se a opção 2 estiver selecionada - Corre este código -->
<div class='tema-2'>
    <button class='btn btn-primary'>botão principal tema 2</button>
</div>

<!-- Mas se a opção 1 estiver selecionada - Então corre este código -->
<div class='tema-1'>
    <button class='btn btn-primary'>botão principal tema 1</button>
</div>
```

Por isso é que eu disse no comentário acima que a sua hierarquia deveria estar desta maneira e não 1 dentro do outro.

Se estiveres à procura de criar uma opção de troca de tema dependendo do tema que o usuário escolher, podes fazer isso como no exemplo deste código abaixo:

### Tens aqui também um exemplo online de como ele irá funcionar num site real: http://jsfiddle.net/6jm3t2au/

```js
$('select[id$=-status][id^=id_item-]').change(function (){
    var color = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    
    $(".tema").removeClass('t1 t2 t3').addClass('t' + $(this).find('option:selected').val());
}).change();
```

```css
.tema    { background-color:white; }
.tema.t1 { background-color:green; }
.tema.t2 { background-color:cornflowerblue; }
.tema.t3 { background-color:orange; }

.tema {
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #C2C2C2;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.tema .container { 
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    height: 70%;
    margin: 10px auto;
 }
.t1 .container { background-color: #B6DC33; width:50%; height: 20%;}
.t2 .container { background-color:cornflowerblue; }
.t3 .container { background-color: #D23131; color: #fff; width:30%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="item-0-status" id="id_item-0-status">
<option value="">-- Escolher tema --</option>
<option value="1">Tema 1 - Verde</option>
<option value="2">Tema 2 - Azul</option>
<option value="3">Tema 3 - Laranja</option>
</select>

<div class="tema">
    <button class='btn btn-primary'>botão principal</button>
    <div class="container">Texto Aleatório</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu estava estudando o código do jquery mobile para verificar como os temas eram processados.

O que acontece com o jquery mobile é que o tema é setado via um atributo `data-theme` e na inicialização do aplicativo todo o html é modificado para utilizar classes.

Por exemplo:

```
<div data-theme="b">
    <button></button>
</div>
```

ficará:

```
<div data-theme="b">
    <button class="ui-btn-b">
</div>
```

Como o script que seta a classe busca pelo tema mais próximo (algo como `.closest('[data-theme]').data('theme')`), a hierarquia dos temas no html é mantida.

Ainda não é a solução que eu estava procurando (que talvez nem exista) pois ainda exige que cada elemento possua uma classe específica por tema, mas é a mais próxima do desejado.